# Peak Detector with Reset

Tags: power-supply, signal-processing, wave

I'm trying to make a N.Peak Detector with reset functions. I've tried various modification to the classic peak detector without any success.
What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Detect the negative peak of the output [Red arrow]
2. Output a Low signal
3. Keep signal to Low till,
4. Output crosses above zero [White arrow]

[image: WaveGen]

Is there a specific name for that kind of circuit?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are there one or two outputs to this circuit?  A peak detector can fairly easily find the most negative voltage. But if you also need to know when it occurred, that is impossible in real-time with an arbitrary waveform; because how do you know the signal won't go further negative later. Please clarify.

Comment: The output can't rise (at all, so specifically it cannot rise above zero) until the detector is reset.  Did you mean it should reset when the *input* crosses zero?

Comment: 1 Output only. You can view it in simulation [link](http://tinyurl.com/yxsufk93) @Mattman944

Comment: You want to know when the most negative signal occurred, that is, one digital output that corresponds in time with the most negative signal?  This is only possible if the waveform shape is known, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing a non-inverting comparator with a 0V reference. It can be latched with positive feedback, but there is no need to.